# connecting an existing new relic account to a heroku rails app to monitor memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, newrelic

I have an existing New Relic account and an existing rails app on Heroku. I am successfully sending data from the Heroku app to New Relic. However I want to see the memory footprint per dyno in New Relic.

All the documentation I could find says to install the add-on via Heroku. I do not want it to provision a new account for me, I just want it to link to my current account. How can I do this? If I already have New Relic installed and working and I add the add-on, will it just link to the account it is already configured for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I work for New Relic. Unfortunately, what you are asking for is not possible. When you install the New Relic add-on for Heroku, it automatically generates a new account with a unique license key and account ID. One of the bonuses of this is that you get Standard subscription for free if you use the add-on.

If you have further account-related questions, however, you're welcome to write to New Relic support to see if you can work something out with your account manager.

Comment: Hi lauradiane, do you have any update on this issue as of now ?

Comment: It's nearly a year later now and I am also wondering whether it's possible to hook an existing heroku app into an existing new relic account?

Comment: if you're still a NR employee, can you update this to say whether @Trein is correct, or whether this is still not possible with NR?

Answer (score 9):

There is actually a workaround for this issue now. You can simply change `NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY` env var:

```
$ heroku config:set NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY='<key_of_your_existing_account>'
```

You find `<key_of_your_existing_account>` under `Account settings > Summary` (right bar with title `Account information`).

After restarting your app, it will show up on your existing account.

You can even customize additional things like:

```
$ heroku config:set NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME='<nice_name>' NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY='<key>'
```

Answer (score 0):

From my testing of Heroku provisioned New Relic accounts and direct ones is that the 'Instances' tab only appears when you are accessing via a Heroku provisioned New Relic - I'm imagine this is because it's a specific setting for the Heroku New Relic account that your application will be in.

Comment: Yeah, that is my understanding as well. My question is basically: Is it possible to hook an existing heroku into an existing new relic in the same way?